# recommended way of profiling distributed tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

Currently, I am using tensorflow estimator API to train my tf model. I am using distributed training that is almost 20-50 workers and 5-30 parameter servers based on the training data size. Since I do not have access to the session, I cannot use run metadata a=with full trace to look at the chrome trace. I see there are two other approaches :

1) [tf.profiler.profile](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/profiler/profile)
2) [tf.train.profilerhook](http://%20https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ProfilerHook)

I am specifically using 
`tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, test_spec)`

where my estimator is a prebuilt estimator.

Can someone give me some guidance (concrete code samples and code pointers will be really helpful since I am very new to tensorflow) what is the recommended way to profile estimator? Are the 2 approaches getting some different information or serve the same purpose? Also is one recommended over another?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can try:

**ProfilerContext**

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/profiler/profile_context.py
Example usage:

```
with tf.contrib.tfprof.ProfileContext('/tmp/train_dir') as pctx:
  train_loop()
```

**ProfilerService**

https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/tensorboard_profiling_keras

You can start a ProfilerServer via `tf.python.eager.profiler.start_profiler_server(port)` on all workers and parameter servers. And use TensorBoard to capture profile.

Note that this is a very new feature, you may want to use `tf-nightly`.

Answer (score 0):

`Tensorflow` have recently added a way to `sample multiple workers`.

Please have a look at the API:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/profiler/experimental/client/trace?version=nightly

The parameter of the above `API` which is important in this context is :

> `service_addr`: A comma delimited string of gRPC addresses of the
> workers to profile. e.g. service_addr='grpc://localhost:6009'
> service_addr='grpc://10.0.0.2:8466,grpc://10.0.0.3:8466'
> service_addr='grpc://localhost:12345,grpc://localhost:23456'

Also, please look at the API,
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/profiler/experimental/ProfilerOptions?version=nightly

The parameter of the above `API` which is important in this context is :

> `delay_ms`: Requests for all hosts to start `profiling` at a timestamp
> that is `delay_ms` away from the current time. `delay_ms` is in
> milliseconds. If zero, each host will start profiling immediately upon
> receiving the request. Default value is None, allowing the `profiler`
> guess the best value.